# Highstock add points to dynamically added series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a highstock chart which:

1. Renders an initial chart with one series
2. After an event (button click) adds another series
3. Dynamically get's updated by adding points (to both series).

1 and 2 work, but adding points to the newly (dynamically) added series doesn't seem to work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/albertsikkema/KGTBB/1/

When I add the series at chart creation time adding points work, so I'm guessing it has something to do with how the series is added.

Comment: You are required to post your code in your question, not at some external site.

Comment: @meagar Sure, but running code explains the problems 10x better then static posted code. I could do both ofcourse.

Comment: You are *required* to post the code in your question. It's not a case of which you think is better. You can use a JSFiddle to *supplement* your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your navigator is an object within chart.series.

If you console log chart.series you will see that:

- 0 = Plot line A
- 1 = The navigator
- 2 = Plot line B

So you are trying to addPoints onto the navigator series, instead do:

```
   chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);                
   chart.series[2].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
```

or, a better method would be to target your series by their name.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It never crossed my mind that the navigator is a chart series in itself. Makes sense.